# MSBuild ExtensionPack Iis6VirtualDirectory create multiple ScriptMaps

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, iis-6, msbuildextensionpack

I'm using the `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis6VirtualDirectory` task to create an *IIsWebDirectory* application as a child of the Default Web Site.  I'm trying to create the application with multiple ScriptMaps (all those required for an ASP.NET 2 website).  However I can't seem to get the task to create the ScriptMaps correctly.  Here's my code:

```xml
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis6VirtualDirectory 
    TaskAction="Create"
    MachineName="$(TargetHostServer)"
    Website="Default Web Site"
    Name="$(IISApplicationName)"
    DirectoryType="IIsWebDirectory"
    Properties="ScriptMaps=.ad,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.adprototype,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.asa,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
.asax,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.ascx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.ashx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.asmx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.asp,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
.aspx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.axd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.browser,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.cd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.cdx,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
.cer,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
.compiled,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.config,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.cs,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.csproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.dd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.exclude,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.idc,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpodbc.dll,5,GET,POST
.java,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.jsl,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.ldb,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.ldd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.lddprototype,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.ldf,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.licx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.master,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.mdb,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.mdf,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.msgx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.refresh,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.rem,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.resources,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.resx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.sd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.sdm,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.sdmDocument,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.shtm,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST
.shtml,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST
.sitemap,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.skin,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.soap,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.stm,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST
.vb,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.vbproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.vjsproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.vsdisco,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG
.webinfo,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" />
```

This just creates a single script map entry with the specification of all the entries on one line.  I've tried specifying newlines with \n and XML character entities but can't get it to create the entries correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the pipe (`|`) character to separate the script maps:

```xml
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis6VirtualDirectory 
    TaskAction="Create"
    MachineName="$(TargetHostServer)"
    Website="Default Web Site"
    Name="$(IISApplicationName)"
    DirectoryType="IIsWebDirectory"
    Properties="ScriptMaps=.ad,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.adprototype,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.asa,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE|.asax,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.ascx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.ashx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.asmx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.asp,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE|.aspx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.axd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.browser,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.cd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.cdx,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE|.cer,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE|.compiled,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.config,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.cs,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.csproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.dd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.exclude,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.idc,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpodbc.dll,5,GET,POST|.java,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.jsl,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.ldb,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.ldd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.lddprototype,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.ldf,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.licx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.master,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.mdb,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.mdf,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.msgx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.refresh,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.rem,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.resources,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.resx,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.sd,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.sdm,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.sdmDocument,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.shtm,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST|.shtml,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST|.sitemap,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.skin,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.soap,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.stm,C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll,5,GET,POST|.vb,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.vbproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.vjsproj,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.vsdisco,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG|.webinfo,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,5,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" />
```